# Get new Invoice ID when created via API using JSON

Tags: json, api, invoice

I have been using XML to create invoices but I am updating my code and switching to using JSON.
When using XML I would get a set of XML returned and part of the data was the new Invoice ID.
However, so it seems at least, when I create a new invoice via the API using JSON, I just get "http/200" (or something like that) returned and no info about what the new invoice ID is!
I need the invoice ID so I can post an attachment.
I tried adding "?summarizeErrors=false" to the end of the URL but nothing was returned unless there was an issue - kinda what it says it does :-)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks, Jeremy

Comment: Please share some snippets of your code. Your server snippets from where you are requesting, so that we can get clear idea of what kind of structure your APIs possess and what language are you using on server end which responds on your request!

Comment: AlphaHash I am not sure what you are meaning by server snippets. I am sending JSON to the Xero API for Invoices I am basically sending the JSON example on the webpage https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices#post with some changes for the customer I am using for testing and posting it to https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices . So, its pretty simple right? Its just not returning any info other than an HTTP 200 response and the invoice IS created, so hmmm....

Answer (score 0):

Its Ok....I resolved it. Wrong value populated in a property in the HTTP control I was using...ugh.